# Why would my local call go to international number?

Tags: calls

Recently in Windows phone, my local calls have been automatically going to international number in the UK , i now can't make any local calls in my area, another area maybe ok, i have no idea what happened but this doesn't look like a carrier problem but a phone problem so, is there an option that i may have messed with in windows phone that take care of that?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail, like what kind of numbers are being called? Also, is resetting your phone an option?

Comment: i have resetted my phone a week ago because apps were crashing and photos were automatically deleted and many more problems, so i did reset my phone but now this new thing is happening, if i call a phone number in my area whether i call it from contacts list or just dial it it will dial a phone number beginning with +44 which is the code of the UK , if i call another number like another state say Michigan,then it's all good.

Comment: Have you checked phone -> Settings if you have the "international calls" Option checked? Try unchecking that.

Comment: Can you make sure any updates for you phone are installed, also check the region and language settings are correct?

Comment: OK I just solved it, i changed language from English (UK) to English (US), thanks

Comment: I had the same problem - some calls were being diverted to 44. The issue was with region - I'm in India and the region was set to UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

- all phone updates installed
- check the region and language settings
- phone -> Settings -> "international calls" option enabled / disabled

Comment: i have installed updates, no option says (international calls) in settings, the strange thing is this only happens when i call my area code numbers.!!

Comment: i did it by changing from English UK to US thanks

Answer (score 1):

A feature called **International assist** is responsible for your problem. Turn off the International assist in your phone.

To turn off International assist follow these steps :

1. Open the Phone application.
2. Tap the 3 dots (...) at the bottom right of the screen.
3. Select Settings.
4. Slide the International Assist toggle to either On or Off.

For further references see [Microsoft FAQ on International Assist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA138384)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your contacts...  If a + (plus sign)  is in front..  Remove it.   Transferring contacts sometimes goes wrong..